# Merge the "questions" and "asking-questions" tags

Tags: support, retag-request

There are two questions on this site tagged with [questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions), and 10 questions tagged [asking-questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions). These tags should probably be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) is a subset of [questions](/questions/tagged/questions).  The latter may be about other question activities - answering, closing, editing, deleting, voting, etc. - or about questions in general.

For example, the tag combination [questions](/questions/tagged/questions)+[voting](/questions/tagged/voting) represents an entirely different subject area from [answers](/questions/tagged/answers)+[voting](/questions/tagged/voting).

In addition, there may be [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) posts that are about [questions](/questions/tagged/questions).  If these were to be tagged [asking-questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions) instead, then it would have a different connotation.  The latter really implies more of a support request.

Admittedly there's a bit of a gray area (and of course there's nothing wrong with having both tags on the same question) but there are clearly cases when a meta question should have one tag and not the other.

At the end of the day I'm inclined to follow MSO's example; they haven't merged those tags despite quite a bit of overlap and high volume.